# iSCSI target volume does not show on 2008 R2 iSCSI Initiator

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

My environment consists of 6 identical Server 2008 R2 blades, 2 identical SANs and 2 different NAS's. I can connect from any server to iSCSI targets on any storage devices (SAN or NAS) and the drives will show in Disk Management, except from one of the blades.

On the problematic blade, the connection to targets on either SAN or NAS is established properly but the volumes don't show up for the connection to either NAS. It works fine for the connection to either SAN. I don't have this problem on any of the other blades.

I have no idea what to do to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention, when the connection from the problematic blade is established to the NAS, the report from the Configuration tab shows this: 

Session #1
 ===========
  Number of Connections = 1

  Connection #1
  ==============
   Target Address = 192.168.1.64
    Target Port = 3260
  #0.  Disk -1
  ========
   Address:Port 7: Bus 0: Target 0: LUN 0

I don't know what to make of "Disk -1" but that's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/163468b1-7a82-4083-b914-0425f6363102/iscsi-initiator-reports-disk-1-?forum=winserverfiles

Essentially, I had to remove MSFT2005iSCSIBusType_0x9 value from the MPIOSupporteddevicelist key at HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\control\MPDEV